# Why am I getting a time out error even though I've specified for my Linked-list traversal to terminate?

Tags: python, while-loop, linked-list

I am reversing a singly- linked list with the following code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        
        if not head: 
            return []
        
        curr = head.next
        prev = head

        while curr:
            curr.next = prev 
            curr = curr.next
            prev = prev.next
        
        return curr
```

I am getting a TIME OUT error- but I can't seem to see the issue. When I run the loop on paper it seems to work fine, any ideas what is causing, what I assume is the loop to not terminate? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure your loop is wrong. The line: `curr.next = prev` immediately overwrites `curr.next`. Now you've lost what was stored at `curr.next`. I assume that you've made your data structure cyclical, where it was acyclical before. Now you enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks quamrana, but what do you mean it 'overwrites' it? My understanding is curr.next = prev in the above is what will help the next item in the list point to the previous one and hence reverse the linked list.

Comment: Yes, you are right that `curr.next = prev` needs to be done at some point in the loop, But you now don't know where `curr.next` used to point to. You need to go back to your paper and pen exercise.

Comment: Ohh I see it now, thanks! It is the line after it that won't make much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- `curr.next` has already been modified by the time you do `curr = curr.next`. So instead of going *forward* in the list, you're going *backward* (since `curr.next` is actually equal to `prev` by that time).
- `head.next` is never modified, yet it should become `None`. You should actually start one step "earlier" in the list, making `curr` equal to `head` and `prev` should be `None`.
- `return curr` is always going to return `None`, as that is the condition by which the `while` loop exits.

Here is a fix:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        curr = head
        prev = None

        while curr:
            nxt = curr.next  # Remember what the next node is before losing the reference
            curr.next = prev  # Rewire.
            prev = curr  # Move the two references one step forward
            curr = nxt  # ... using the saved reference
        
        return prev   # Return what was the tail node, but now is the new head
```

So we use a temporary variable `nxt` here. You could also use tuple assignment... then you don't need the explicit temporary variable:

```
        while curr:
            curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next
```